# Unable to align vertices along a custom orientation

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

Why when I scale vertices by zero with custom orientation, instead of getting a straight line, I get a little bit curved line.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can see that **vertices aren't perfectly aligned**. 

What I expected is to get perfectly straight line aligned along the custom orientation as shown in the picture below:

 [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem in your file?

Just in case.. to flatten to a plane .. in 2.79..

- Select 3 points which define the plane
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> create the Custom Orientation
- With pivot set to 'Active' as you have done, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>
- To check the result, <kbd>F</kbd> make a face out of your arc, select it, and set an orthographic view to look straight down its side by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>

Comment: How come you don't see a problem? These edges on the left that aren't perfectly straight are scaled by zero along a custom orientation  that I had defined earlier, and that right one is scaled along a global axis and then rotated.

Comment: @blablaalb ..  reopened, double-checked.. selected both arcs, on each, filled with F, looked straight with shift 3, Shift-D duplicaled end verts to ensure straight line to compare .. looks fine! Mystery.. are you sure you're looking straight on? They're not straight _to each other_...

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/BLNrn04/Clipboard01.png This is what I see from right orthographic view

Comment: Good.. so do I.. they're both flat/straight, but not parallel to each other... the one on the left is not orthogonal to global YZ, .. is that what you wanted?

Comment: Ok sorry , apparently my custom orientation wasn't  orthogonal to the global YZ axes. Sorry.