# How can I straighten a bunch of vertices into a straight line? (Odd angle)

Tags: modeling

As you can see on the Top Ortho view, the selected vertices are a bit of a mess, and I need them to be perfectly aligned like the green line I draw next to them, while keeping the same, circle-ish shape.

How can I go about it?

I tried a few methods posted on this site and elesewhere but I never managed to make it the way I want it.

I would also prefer avoiding redoing the complete thing over again.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132749/unable-to-align-vertices-along-a-custom-orientation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you. Enable LoopTools in preferences then select the faces concerned rather than the vertices. Press W, choose "LoopTools", choose "Flatten".

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it. Upvoted and accepted answer.